# How Do I Resolve this "An error was captured in current module: TypeError: e.parse is not a function"

Tags: vue.js, shopware6, shopware6-api

How do I solve this Vue Js error on Shopware 6 Administration. The module is suppose to select a column in the database table.

PS. This is the complete code. I'm trying to read data from the database and view it in the twig template.

```
const { Component, Mixin } = Shopware;
const { Criteria } = Shopware.Data;
import template from './store-settings-page.html.twig'
Component.register('store-settings-page', {
template,

inject: [
 'repositoryFactory'
 ],

metaInfo() {
   return {
       title: this.$createTitle()
   };
 },

data: function () {

 return {
     entity: undefined,
     storeData: null,
     entityId: '4e2891496c4e4587a3a7efe587fc8c80',
     secret_key: 'hdkkjjsmk538dncbjmns',
     public_key: '1destinoDet2123lefmoddfk@#$$%O',
 }

},

computed: {

 storeKeysRepository() {
     return this.repositoryFactory.create('store_keys');
 },
 
},

created() {


     this.storeKeysRepository
         .get(this.entityId, Shopware.Context.api)
         .then(entity => {
             this.entity = entity;
         });

         console.log(entity);
 },
 

});
```

Comment: The error is quite generic. Please share the entirety your components code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code has been updated @dneustadt

Comment: Also include the markup of your template in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if my knowledge of Vue & JS is a bit off, based on how I see Shopware codes it, I recommend data to be written like this:

```
data() {
        return {
            ...
        };
}
```

I would also try to strip your file to the bear minimum to see when the error disappears.

Another thing to check is if you are running a JS file or TS file. Maybe it's having a hard time parsing your file because you are extending `store-settings-page` and it assumes it should be TypeScript?

Answer (score -1):

```
this.storeKeysRepository
         .get(this.entityId, Shopware.Context.api)
         .then(entity => {
             this.entity = entity;
             console.log(this.entity);
         });
```

This will do the trick

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).